# How to send all requests through one interface?

Tags: networking, router, openwrt

I want that my router connect to the henet tunnel and direct all queries through the tunnel.
LEDE Reboot 17.01.4

My setup:

```
Modem(Router)
      | (Modem LAN to WAN OpenWrt)
      V
OpenWrt Router with He.net Tunnel 
      |> (LAN1/2/3/4 to PCs)
```

my config */etc/config/network*

```
config interface 'loopback'
        option ifname 'lo'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
        option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
        option ula_prefix 'fdc1:27c0:08d1::/48'

config interface 'lan'
        option type 'bridge'
        option proto 'static'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
        option ip6assign '60'
        option ipaddr '192.168.1.100'
        option ifname 'eth0 eth1'
        option gateway '192.168.1.1'
        option dns '192.168.1.1'

config interface 'wan'
        option _orig_bridge 'true'
        option ifname 'eth1'
        option _orig_ifname 'eth1'
        option proto 'dhcp'
        option type 'bridge'

config interface 'wan6'
        option ifname 'eth1'
        option type 'bridge'
        option proto 'dhcpv6'

config switch
        option name 'switch0'
        option vlan '1'
        option ports '0 1 2 3 4 5t'

config switch_vlan
        option device 'switch0'
        option vlan '1'
        option ports '0 1 2 3 4'

config interface 'henet'
        option proto '6in4'
        option peeraddr '216.myip.98'
        option ip6addr '2001:myip::2/64'
        option ip6prefix '2001:myip::/64'
        option tunnelid 'mytunnelid'
        option username 'mylogin'
        option password 'mypassword'
```

and */etc/config/firewall*

```
config defaults
        option syn_flood '1'
        option input 'ACCEPT'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option forward 'ACCEPT'

config zone
        option name 'lan'
        option input 'ACCEPT'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option forward 'ACCEPT'
        option network 'lan'

config zone
        option name 'wan'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option input 'REJECT'
        option forward 'REJECT'
        option masq '1'
        option mtu_fix '1'
        option network 'wan henet'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-DHCP-Renew'
        option src 'wan'
        option proto 'udp'
        option dest_port '68'
        option target 'ACCEPT'
        option family 'ipv4'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-Ping'
        option src 'wan'
        option proto 'icmp'
        option icmp_type 'echo-request'
        option family 'ipv4'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-IGMP'
        option src 'wan'
        option proto 'igmp'
        option family 'ipv4'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-DHCPv6'
        option src 'wan'
        option proto 'udp'
        option src_ip 'fc00::/6'
        option dest_ip 'fc00::/6'
        option dest_port '546'
        option family 'ipv6'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-MLD'
        option src 'wan'
        option proto 'icmp'
        option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
        list icmp_type '130/0'
        list icmp_type '131/0'
        list icmp_type '132/0'
        list icmp_type '143/0'
        option family 'ipv6'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Input'
        option src 'wan'
        option proto 'icmp'
        list icmp_type 'echo-request'
        list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
        list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
        list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
        list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
        list icmp_type 'bad-header'
        list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
        list icmp_type 'router-solicitation'
        list icmp_type 'neighbour-solicitation'
        list icmp_type 'router-advertisement'
        list icmp_type 'neighbour-advertisement'
        option limit '1000/sec'
        option family 'ipv6'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Forward'
        option src 'wan'
        option dest '*'
        option proto 'icmp'
        list icmp_type 'echo-request'
        list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
        list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
        list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
        list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
        list icmp_type 'bad-header'
        list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
        option limit '1000/sec'
        option family 'ipv6'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-IPSec-ESP'
        option src 'wan'
        option dest 'lan'
        option proto 'esp'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
        option name 'Allow-ISAKMP'
        option src 'wan'
        option dest 'lan'
        option dest_port '500'
        option proto 'udp'
        option target 'ACCEPT'

config include
        option path '/etc/firewall.user'

config forwarding
        option dest 'wan'
        option src 'lan'
```

Comment: @grawity this is tunnel ipv6 over ipv4, i have public ip at home, this is what he.net give me: https://pastebin.com/CZQ1RNHy bot this dosent work in my configuration, I have Modem(Router) LAN -> WAN (Modem LAN to WAN OpenWrt) -> LAN to PCs

Comment: @grawity Configuration on He.net works, I added manually to one laptop by ifconfig configuration and works, now I want the whole network to have access to ipv6 by router.

Comment: @grawity How to assign IPv6 address to you LAN?

Comment: @grawity http://i.img.itunix.eu/0-4733d.png